# subclass giving me "symbol is not found" error for the abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

So I took some of my comp sci professor's example classes and tried to compile them to learn more about it, but I get a "symbol is not found" error. All the files are in the same folder. Can anyone tell me how to fix this or what's going on?

Here is the abstract class:

```
    package abstractclass;

/**
   The Element class is introduced to illustrate the use of
    abstract classes.  In this revised version of the PersonSet
    class example, the Person class will inherit from this
    abstract class.  The purpose of the abstract class Element
    is to introduce the "common class protocol" for all of its
    subclasses.  That common class protocol is introduced using
    abstract as well as fully implemented methods.  The abstract
    methods are:
                  readIn
                  display
                  equals
                  clone
    In addition, the abstract class Element fully implements the
    getClassName method.
*/

    public abstract class Element
   {

   // Access method

   /**
      The getClassName method returns the name of the calling object's
    class.
    @return the name of the calling object's class
   */

       public String getClassName()
      {
         // Local data ...
         String resultStr;
                       // Result of applying toString method to
                          // the calling object
         int whereAt;  // Where the @ symbol is in resultStr

         // Logic ...
         resultStr = this.toString();
         whereAt = resultStr.indexOf('@');
         resultStr = resultStr.substring(0,whereAt);
         whereAt = resultStr.indexOf('.');
         return resultStr.substring(whereAt + 1);
      }

      // Abstract methods readIn, display, equals and clone.
      // A direct subclass must implement these abstract methods
    // unless the direct subclass is itself declared "abstract"

       public abstract void readIn();

       public abstract void display();

       public abstract boolean equals(Element dobj);

       public abstract Element clone();
   }
```

Here is the subclass Person:

```
        package abstractclass;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

    public class Person extends Element
   {
      private String name;        
      private String eMail;       

       public Person()
      {
         name = "";
         eMail = "";
      }

       public Person (String aName)
      {
         name = new String(aName.toUpperCase());
      }

       public Person (Person originalPerson)
      {
         name = new String(originalPerson.name);
         eMail = new String(originalPerson.eMail);
      }

       public String getName()
      {
         return new String(name);
      }

       public String getEMail()
      {
         return new String(eMail);
      }

       public void setName(String aName)
      {
         name = new String(aName.toUpperCase());
      }

       public void setEMail(String anEMail)
      {
         eMail = new String(anEMail);
      }

       public void readIn()
      {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.print("Name:   ");
         name = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
         System.out.print("E-Mail: ");
         eMail = keyboard.nextLine();
      }

       public void display()
      {
         System.out.println("Name:   " + name);
         System.out.println("E-mail: " + eMail);
      }

       public boolean equals(Element otherPerson)
      {
         return name.equals(((Person) otherPerson).name);
      }

       public Element clone()
      {
         Person theClone = new Person();
         theClone.name = new String(name);
         theClone.eMail = new String(eMail);
         return theClone;
      }
```

Here is the error it gives me when I try and compile the person class:

```
    Person.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public class Person extends Element
                                ^
  symbol: class Element
Person.java:147: error: cannot find symbol
       public boolean equals(Element otherPerson)
                             ^
  symbol:   class Element
  location: class Person
Person.java:158: error: cannot find symbol
       public Element clone()
              ^
  symbol:   class Element
  location: class Person
3 errors
```

Comment: Just a note : override the `equals` method from the `Object` class instead of implementing your own.

Comment: How are you compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that both classes are in a folder called `abstractclass` as expected by the compiler. The compiler expects the folder name to match the package name when locating dependent classes.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch! I'm confused though*, why do they have to be in the same folder named abstractclass?

Comment: You can "get away" with using an incorrectly named package structure for a single class but when you need to locate a 2nd dependent class in the same package the compiler will fail - hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both the files in abstractclass folder because you have put

```
package abstractclass;
```

for both the classes